# Bootstrap 4 navbar example doesn't work correctly on my computer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just starting with Bootstrap 4 and copy code from Bootstrap navbar docs and it shows something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSNBw.png), when I click the small button it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3499.png). Here is head

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and here is body:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

I've changed nothing from the docs. I've searched for this problem but it's all about wrong position of script tag, and it doesn't look like my issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the bootstrap 3 navbar but bootstrap 4 resources

either use bootstrap 3 css or use this navbar instead
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: OMG, you save my day! btw their docs is like a maze